# I want to split the value by using selenium and Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, cucumber

I have an element:

```
<div class=v-image__image v-image__image--contain" style="background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/cn_static_files/app-logo/plaid-logo.png"); background-position: center center;"><div> == $0
```

[image: Element Picture]

From above element i want to extract only "style" attribute value so i used

```
driver.driver.findElements("ElementXpath").getAttribute("style");
```

And from "style" attribute i want only:
https://storage.googleapis.com/cn_static_files/app-logo/plaid-logo.png or
plaid-logo.png text not all the value of "style" attribute

My effective code:

```
String Value = driver.findElements(ApplicationLogoElement)getAttribute("style");

String ExtractedValue = Value.substring(Value.indexOf("(") +2, Value.indexOf(")") - 1); 
    //tried this also

String ExtractedValue= TableRowValue.replaceAll("(.*?/)", " ");    //and tried this also

System.out.println("Final extracted value is: " + ExtractedValue);
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get https://storage.googleapis.com/cn_static_files/app-logo/plaid-logo.png, below is the code

```
String ExtractedValue= Value.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].replace("\"","");
```

To get plaid-logo.png, below is the code

```
String ExtractedValue=Value.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].replace("\"","");
int a= ExtractedValue.lastIndexOf("/");
ExtractedValue= ExtractedValue.substring(a).replace("/","");
```

Comment: I Appreciate your words. Thank you so much. Can you please tell how did you pass the split? I mean where I can understand it better? Any link ?

Comment: @BiswamberKhandei I have 1st Split it with )  and taken  1st part of the array.. The escape character for ) or ( is \\. the i split the result with ( and taken 2nd part of the array. Then i replace " with nothing  from the result. the escape character for " is \.

Comment: Then i have got the last index of / from the result and used substring to get characters from the last index of / in the result  and replaced / with nothing.

Comment: Hey @Sonali Das it is throwing me an error: 31mjava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: 31mjava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1   
         :This error I was trying to extract only plaid-logo.png

Comment: can you pls paste ur code pls

Comment: for (WebElement count : RowCount) {
    String TableRowValue = count.getAttribute("style");

    // To extract only ApplicationLogo.png

    String ExtractedValue = TableRowValue.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[0].replace("\"", "");
    int a = ExtractedValue.lastIndexOf("/");
    ExtractedValue = ExtractedValue.substring(a).replace("/", "");

    // To extract only application logo URL
    // String ExtractedValue=
    // TableRowValue.split("\\)")[0].split("\\(")[1].replace("\"","");
    StoreRowCount.add(ExtractedValue);
   }

Comment: you are looping in a for loop. Do style attribute every time returns the same text as you mentioned in the question

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solved it Here is my effective code.
WebElement LogoElement = driver.findElements(ApplicationLogoElement);
String ApplicationLogoValue = LogoElement.getAttribute("style");
String ExtractedValue =ApplicationLogoValue.substring(ApplicationLogoValue.indexOf("\"")+1,ApplicationLogoValue.lastIndexOf("\""));
System.out.println("Application logo URL is: "+ExtractedValue);